# Does "an injection of a drug" refer to a medical drug or an illegal drug?

Tags: meaning

Will it be confusing if I hear someone say "an injection of a drug", since the word *drug* has the meaning of either *a medicine* or *an illegal narcotic substance*?

Comment: If there's no context, "a[n] injection of a drug" could be either medical or recreational. The only tip I can think of is that usually unspecified "drugs" (plural) are illicit. Is there a specific instance you're unsure about?

Comment: There isn't any specific context. I just wonder if the word "drug" can make people confuse when it is used alone. And, does "a drug" in most cases refer to "a medicine"?

Comment: *Drug* in English doesn't refer specifically to legal drugs or illegal drugs.  Whether something is a drug is a separate attribute from whether it's legal.  But a few phrases have associations one way or the other, like "buying/selling drugs" (illegal) or "drug store" (legal).  By the way, whether a drug is a narcotic or not is yet another separate attribute.

Comment: In general, I'd associate *an injection of a drug* with a legal act.  *shooting up* would be an illegal act.  As a rule of thumb, the more professional it sounds the more likely to be legal, and the more slang is used the more likely to be illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing. "Injection of a drug" is not a very suitable "bed side" phrase (see "bed side manners") for medical practitioner such as doctor or nurse to use.

It focuses on the crude act of penetrating the skin with a needle, which requires us to distance ourselves from the subject who is receiving the procedure. Therefore, this usage could appear in a technical context, like a medical or scientific paper, or about injection of narcotics ("safe injection site").

A softer word used around patients would be "administration of a drug" or something. I can't imagine a nurse coming around and saying, "we're going to inject you with the drug now". Yikes!

So your intuition is right that there is something about "inject the drug", but the distinction doesn't revolve around legal versus illegal, but rather about whether we have empathy for the recipient of the procedure, including the concern about the recipient's emotional response to our choice of words in regard to the procedure.

When a speaker uses "inject" for narcotic users, it's because he or she is comfortable discussing the issue without sugar-coating the language, or else doesn't feel empathy toward the recipients of a procedure when it is self-inflicted.

Note that the execution method "lethal injection" is, of course, legal, too.

Answer (score 3):

Anything may be confusing or ambiguous if taken out of context, but in actual discourse phrases and sentences do not appear without a context.

For that matter, *a medicine* and *an illegal narcotic substance* are not necessarily exclusive: a narcotic substance taken for medicinal purposes may have been illegally obtained.

Comment: "Anything may be confusing or ambiguous if taken out of context, but in actual discourse phrases and sentences do not appear without a context." I think this is something that's been coming up a lot lately, and is very important to mention. I've been trying to think of a way to get this message out to more of our users, but haven't come up with anything thus far.

Comment: @WendiKidd Perhaps "Insufficient Context" should be added to the Close menu.

Comment: That's what the "Details" one is supposed to be for... But it might need a rewrite.